# Maximum websocket connections per client

Tags: websocket, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am developing a tool to load test my signalR application, using Signal R Client HUB APIs.

I want to test my application behavior over the websockets against 10K client.

The issue is that my Tool is not able to create new connection after certain number of connections.The maximum connections it can create is in the range of 2000-3000 only.

I am not able to figure out what is the reason behind this. I checked on server side and found no issues.As server is able to response to browsers clients after.

The error getting logged in tool is:

```
System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket.<ConnectAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket.<ConnectAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Transports.WebSocketTransport.<PerformConnect>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Transports.WebSocketTransport.<DoReconnect>d__9.MoveNext()
```

Sometimes this tool gets hang when websocket client increases to 1700 or sometimes more than that.

This tool is .NET 4.5 windows application. The signalR server I am hitting is also on same network.

I am executing certain methods in my signalR service. One method is to pass input data from client to server and another method which client is subscribing to receive data from server.

Also I tested this tool from different machine from where it is able to generate the distributed load but I don't want to run multiple instance of the tool. My question is why single instance is not able to generate bulk websocket request to my signal R service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explain a little bit more about what do you do in the test, and also where are executing client and server.

If you are sending messages non-stop, probably you may be already saturating the channel. What is the throughput of the NIC when the connections starts to fail? What is the CPU usage? Maybe your client or your server cannot get going with so much data.

Have you tried to run two client in parallel? Maybe the problem is your client, that is unable of handling that amount of connections appropriately.

**UPDATE**

You should use some form of threading to create multiple parallel connections and keep them alive during the test. Please take a look at my [WebSocket echo load generator](https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketEchoLoadGenerator) that I use for doing performance tests, and follow the approach to create a SignalR load generator.

Comment: Thanks Vtortola for reply..I have updated my question with answer to your queries...

Comment: Is the tool trying to run a thread per connection ? How have you approached the multiple connections and threading?

Comment: No. I am not using any threading here..Let me know if any solution here if using thread I can spawn multiple clients. Also one thing I observered here is that after certain clients say 2000 or more I am getting Transport timedout and also after sometime it starts disconnecting the clients which are already connected. and in server IIS logs I found out signalr/abort logs.

Comment: No threading at all? How are you creating the multiple connections then?

Comment: I am creating clients in a loop.

Comment: I updated my answer, please take a look at my code and try to implement something like that.